# Point light attached to a particle system is always on

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particle-system

I have a muzzle flash (particle system) and there's a point light attached to it, but it is always on. How do I make it turn on only during the player is shooting and the muzzle flash is on? (The point light is a child of the muzzle flash object)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

the [light](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.LightsModule-light.html) is supposed to be a **prefab**, not an instance in your scene

> Select what Light **Prefab** you want to base your particle lights on.

It will then be instantiated accordingly by the particle system itself.

See also [Unity Learn - Particle Lights](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/particle-system-lights#)